# Rails appending empty query parameters (/new?) to my URLS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, parameters

There might be an obvious answer to this question... but I'm not sure where to look.

For some reason, rails is appending empty query strings to my URLs on some redirects.  I have a user "dashboard" page, where they can click on a button to create a new "foo".

When I click on the button to go to this path, the url reads: "localhost/foo/new?"

I don't know where this phantom query parameter is coming from.... I don't even know if it is a big deal, but for some reason I feel that it could hurt me on the caching or SEO end.  Does anyone have some pointers as to where to look?

**UPDATE 1**

The code I'm using to generate the link to the new_foo item (using HAML & bootstrap):

```
= button_to "New Foo!", new_foo_path, :method => :get, :class => btn_class
```

The code in the controller looks like this:

```
def new
  @foo = Foo.new(:my_attribute => 2500)
end
```

Regarding the second comment - I don't imagine that this object would be persisted in the database at this point?  I thought that the Rails object.new method just built it in memory, and doesn't get persisted until #save.

**UPDATE 2**

In changing the code to a "link_to" the problem seems to have gone away... Could you explain this?

Comment: Can you add in the code you're using when calling the new_foo helper to generate the new foo link?

Comment: Check whether `foo` is persisted in the database.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys - I've added additional details in the question. I may have even figured it out, but don't know why! @luacassus - I wouldn't think that the object would be persisted in the database at this point... usually the new action just creates an object in memory for the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

button_to is different with link_to.
button_to actually will build a form in page. the form will be like this.

```
<form action="/foo/new" class="button_to" method="get">
   <div><input type="submit" value="abc"></div>
</form>
```

it is a get form and when click submit, will use the input fields which in the form as parameters. the action's query won't be used. for example:

```
= button_to new_foo_path(:test => true)
#=> <form action="/foo/new?test=true" class="button_to" method="get">
      <div><input type="submit" value="abc"></div>
    </form>
```

when you click submit, url will be "/foo/new?", the test=true gone. it's a specialty in html. may be a more example will make you understand.

```
= form_tag(new_foo_path(:test => true), :method => :get) do
   = hidden_field_tag "field_in_form", "true"
   = submit_tag "submit"
```

after you click submit. the url will be "/foo/new?field_in_form=true".I think the "?" always appear when you submit a get form contain input(include submit_tag).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Blade.  Think I've got a handle on this now!